# Why does the searching of an item in my sqlite table, using python, only work when the data is a number saved as text?

Tags: python, sqlite, variables

I'm trying to create a contact book as a personal project. In the 'find_contact()' function, when I use the 'emaiL' variable to perform a query, it error message says that the data (I pre-recorded in the table) doesn't exist. But when I changed the variable to be used to query to 'phoneNum' (which is a number in text form) the query worked. How do I go about this please?

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('contactBook.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
records = cur.fetchall()

#create table
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
        first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
        last_name TEXT,
        phone_number TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        email,
        address TEXT,
        UNIQUE(phone_number, email)
     )""")
 #conn.close()

def save_contact():
     save_contact.firstName = input("First name of contact: ")
     lastName = input("Last name of contact: ")
     phoneNumber = input("Phone number of contact: ")
     email_ = input("Email of contact: ")
     address_ = input("Address of contact: ")
     cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO contacts (first_name, last_name,phone_number, 
email,address)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
       (save_contact.firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email_, address_))
     conn.commit()

def find_contact():
    emaiL = input('Enter email: ')
    query = f'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = {emaiL}'''
    lua = f'''SELECT first_name, phone_number FROM contacts WHERE email = {emaiL}'''
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts (email) VALUES (?)", (email,))
    cur.execute(query)
    #conn.commit()
    print(cur.execute(lua))

req = input("Hello, would you like to save or search for a contact: ")

if str.lower(req) == 'save':
   save_contact()
   x = save_contact.firstName
   print("You have successfully saved " + x + "'s details")

elif str.lower(req) == 'search':
   find_contact()
```

The test run was:

```
Hello, would you like to save, search or update for a contact: 
search
Enter email: mine
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\GLORIA\Desktop\MINE\db.py", line 60, in <module>
    find_contact()
  File "c:\Users\GLORIA\Desktop\MINE\db.py", line 33, in 
    find_contact
    cur.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: mine
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message you get including complete traceback.

Comment: I've edited it to show traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```py
> query = f'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = {emaiL}'''
> ```

If the value of the variable `emaiL` is the string `'mine'`, this creates the SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = mine
```

but in this statement, `mine` would be interpreted by SQLite as a column name. If you want it to be interpreted as a string, quotes would need to be added:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = "mine"
```

However, don't try to adjust the string formatting line, `query = f'''...'''` to add the quotes, instead use a parameterized statement with `?` as a placeholder, like you did for the other SQL statements in your code.

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = ?'
cur.execute(query, (emaiL,))
```

See [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) for reasons to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In the query `query = f'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE last_name = {emaiL}'''` is it not supposed to be `f'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = {emaiL}'''`?

Comment: It is, I used last_name to see if it was only email that had the problem and forgot to change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your `{emaiL}` doesn't have quotes for the email in the query, like this:

```
f'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = '{emaiL}' '''
```

If you print out your current query variable, you'll get `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = mine`, which isn't valid. You want to get the string `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = 'mine'`.